# cURL (API) en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl

Estoy accediendo a la API de una URL a traves de cURL y busco hacerlo a traves de Python. No se si esto se pueda hacer pero me solucionaria mucho mi trabajo.

Los pasos que estoy realizando son:
Introduzco este codigo a mi terminal  y me devuelve la respuesta:

Codigo:

```
curl 'https://partners.com/api/v2/login' -d 'username=user&password=pass'
```

Respuesta:

```
{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1YTAxZGNlZjlkNmQ1ZTAwMDI3YWMyNGEifQ.zcC5w6SHL-PN4kZgnDVh75jqLJ5BsKP27YZi7xaiels","token_type":"bearer","user_id":"5a01dcef9d6d5e00027ac24a"}Imac-Office:~ Martin$
```

Ahora bien, el toquen debo copiarlo e introducirlo donde dice TOKEN

```
curl 'https://partners.com/api/v2/traffic-channels' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -d '{"trafficChannel":{"name":"tc10","status":0,"billedEvent":"ai","env":"desktop","dealType":"fixed_price","cost":2,"floor":2.5,"optimizeAllAdSources":true,"optimizeFor":"fillRate","publisher":"5a01e576becbf9000255f29c"}}'
```

Quiero hacer un codigo en python donde pueda ponerlo todo junto, algo asi:

```
curl 'https://partners.com/api/v2/login' -d 'username=user&password=pass'

curl 'https://partners.com/api/v2/traffic-channels' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOiI1YTAxZGNlZjlkNmQ1ZTAwMDI3YWMyNGEifQ.zcC5w6SHL ' -d '{"trafficChannel":{"name":"tc10","status":0,"billedEvent":"ai","env":"desktop","dealType":"fixed_price","cost":2,"floor":2.5,"optimizeAllAdSources":true,"optimizeFor":"fillRate","publisher":"5a01e576becbf9000255f29c"}}'
```

Que automaticamente capte la respuesta del token y la pegue en la siguiente linea de codigo.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: No es más fácil hacer una llamada http desde Python, directamente?

Comment: Como seria lo que decis? Depende lo que me muestres veo si puede servir

Comment: Algo como esto: https://pythonbc.com/blog/la-libreria-requests-de-python/ No te pongo código en una respuesta porque apenas se Python, pero en cualquier lenguaje existen ya herramientas para hacer fácil lo que quieres hacer sin necesidad de apoyarse en programas externos